# Adding to the documention in the gnome-builder side bar

Tags: gnome, gnome-builder

Gnome builder features a sidebar which contains documentation for various api. On my system it seems to have three pieces of documentation: "Shell" (seems to be a C++ api for the gnome shell) "St" (apparently the styleable actors widget api) and Totem (a api for creating totem plugins). None of these are very useful to me.

Is it possible to change or add to the documentation shown in this sidebar? For example I would like to have the numpy and scipy documentation there.

My builder version is 3.18.1, but I have also tried on version 3.20